# Different html content with robot browser using selenium webdriver instead of human browser

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to parse webpage with python selenium webdriver.
I've found something starnge in html content. It is different when I use robot browser instead of when I'm getting same page with human browser.
For example just part of webpage that I get:

```
<p>
  <label>
    <span>
      Some text 1
      <br>
      <i>header 1</i>
      Some text 2
      <br>
      <i>header 2</i>
      Some text 3
      <br>
      <i>header 3</i>
      Some text 4
    </span>
  </label>
</>
```

In human browser I get it as is, but in robot browser I get it without one section, I missed `header 2` and `Some text 3`.
I was trying to analize request headers in human browser and robot browser to find difference and I've found one. In human request headers there is not cookie. But in robot browser in request headers I can see this

`cookie: _ga=GA1.2.153230535.1622710383; _gid=GA1.2.1454651548.1622710383; __gads=ID=fb2caae82787b530-2265cda036c80043:T=1622710436:RT=1622710436:S=ALNI_MZ0bzRzYOmpiZrGnBzbdMQl7UHCRw`

I don't understand why it is so. Can anyone explain? How can server distinguish my robot browser and send different content instead of human browser?

Comment: Ask website owners, you didnt posted code or website domain.

Comment: @Wonka, I don't think that website owners like that someone parse data from their website))

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by imitating the mouse movement. So now before click on element, I use selenium webdriver.ActionChains for imitate mouse movement.

```
search_input = browser.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="search_input"]')
sleep(0.5)
browser.action_chain.move_to_element(search_input)
sleep(0.5)
browser.action_chain.click(search_input)
sleep(0.5)
search_input.clear()
sleep(0.5)
```

Now all content that I got like in human browser